# Modify the x axis labels of the library (ggseqplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, traminer

I use the `library (ggseqplot)` to display a `TraMineR` graph in `ggplot2` format.

`library(ggseqplot)`

`plot <- ggseqdplot(mvad.seq)`

I get this figure:
[image]

I would like to modify the x axis labels which is continuous from y1 to y1440 (1 minute to 1440), and add y100, y200, y300, etc.

I can't transmit the data because it's quite heavy. Is there any way of changing the axis labels to suit us? This library is supposed to make things easier.
Many thanks!

Comment: You can use `ggplot` functions like in other settings: so check `scale_x_continuous` or `scale_x_date` (depending on your data), check the `breaks` argument.

Comment: Also, please provide a reproducible data set, otherwise we can't give you proper solutions

Answer (score 3):

The library indeed makes plotting easier, assuming some familiarity with `ggplot2` functions (just like `TraMineR`'s plot functions require some knowledge of base R's `plot` environment if you want to modify them). In this case, you need to know how to change the appearance of axis scales and that the position scale of the sequences - usually indicating time points - is conceived as a discrete scale. Hence, you need to use the function `scale_x_discrete()` to adjust the axis.

```r
library(ggseqplot)

# Create a sequence object from the mvad data set
data(mvad)
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[,17:86])


# Plot the sequence object: dplot with desired break points
ggseqdplot(mvad.seq) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(1, seq(10,70,10)))
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

```r
# ... add own labels
ggseqdplot(mvad.seq) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(1, seq(10,70,10)), 
                   labels = paste0("y", c(1, seq(10,70,10))))
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks! I displayed the entropy with `ggseqdplot(mvad.seq, with.entropy = TRUE)` but I would like to change the label, to translate it in french for example. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: You have to use `scale_color_identity()` (maybe there are other options ...):
```ggseqdplot(mvad.seq, with.entropy = T) + scale_color_identity(guide = "legend", name = NULL, labels = "entropie")```